# Automation of ssh session using jsch library in java

Tags: java, automation

I am automating the ssh session using java, using this code i am able to login and i get the output on screen, but after this, after we enter the application to run in the ssh session, it doesn't take username and password as it requires keyboard interactions like TAB and ENTER and function keys etc, so is there a way to send keyboard events in place of commands so that automation is successful?

```
public class jschputty {

public static void main(String args[])
{   
 String host="x.x.x.x";
 String user="username";
 String password="password";
 String command1="ls -ltr\t";

 try{

    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected");

    ChannelExec channel=(ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));

  channel.setCommand(command);
    channel.connect();
           String msg=null;
           while((msg=in.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(msg);
           }                  
                channel.disconnect();
                session.disconnect();
                System.out.println("DONE");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

}

Comment: What you are doing is making an SFTP connection to an SFTP server. Just like you can do with the client application called 'putty'. You are NOT interacting with putty in any way with this code.

Comment: @Gimby - technically, ssh, not sftp, but you are correct that putty is in no way involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send output to the remote session, i would suggest that you write to the OutputStream returned by `channel.getOutputStream()`.

Comment: thanks, i was trying to use this in my code, can you please help me with a sample for this, as to how to use this to write it to output stream , with reference to my code?

Comment: InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
    channel.connect();
    out.write("ls -lrt\n".getBytes());
    out.flush();

Comment: this is what i have tried but it seems i am wrong here with sumthing

Comment: @XtremeCore - why?  you are providing no details as to what your actual problem is.  you should update your question with specific details.